# Exit strategy doesn't work

Tags: java, while-loop, exit

I'm trying to make a Exit strategy in a small game.
But when I enter yes it runs te script again but when i finish the script doesn't ask:

> Do you want to try again

but it starts again without using the exit strategy.

how do I need to make the exit strategy working when it's running for the second time?

```
package steenpapierschaar1;


public class SteenPapierSchaar1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final int rock = 1 ;   // waarde van Rock
        final int paper = 2;  // waarde van paper
        final int scissor = 3;// waarde van scissor
        Scanner KeyBoard = new Scanner (System.in);// naam scanner input
        Random rand = new Random();
        boolean playing = true;
        boolean ans = false;
        String ans0 = "";


        while(playing == true){
            int AI = rand.nextInt((3 - 1) +1) + 1;// maakt int AI een random getal nog niet af moet een range in komen
               System.out.println("choose 1 for rock, 2 for paper and 3 for scissor"); // string met keuze voor User
            int UserChoice = KeyBoard.nextInt();// waarde van UserChoice

                if (AI == rock && UserChoice == paper || AI == paper && UserChoice == scissor || AI == scissor && UserChoice == rock){
                System.out.println("You win");
                if (AI == rock)
                System.out.println("The computer did rock");
                if (AI == paper)
                System.out.println("The computer did Paper");
                if (AI == scissor)
                System.out.println("The computer did Scissor");
                }

                else if (AI == UserChoice) {
                System.out.println("Draw");
                if (AI == rock);
                System.out.println("The Computer did rock");
                if (AI == paper)
                System.out.println("The Computer did paper");
                if (AI == scissor)
                System.out.println("The Computer did scissors");
                }

                else if (AI == rock && UserChoice == scissor || AI == paper && UserChoice == rock || AI == scissor && UserChoice == paper){
                System.out.println("You Lose");
                if (AI == rock)
                System.out.println("The Computer did rock");
                if (AI == paper)
                System.out.println("The Computer did paper");
                if (AI == scissor)
                System.out.println("The Computer did scissors");
                }              

                 while (ans == false){
            System.out.println("Do you want to try again?");
            ans0 = KeyBoard.nextLine();
            ans0 = ans0.toLowerCase();
            switch(ans0){
                case "yes":
                    ans = true;
                    playing = true;
                    break;
                case "no":
                    ans = true;
                    playing = false;
                    break;
                }                
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you set playing = false?

Comment: You should probably also refactor the duplicated checks of what the AI chose for clarity.

Comment: The second while only loops the System.out... or am I missing sth? The switch is never entered.

Comment: Perhaps reading the Java docs on switches will help https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because there is not a { } block after the while condition the while block is only the one line after it.  So it is simply repeating the SysOut endlessly.

This is more what you are attempting to do.

****EDIT*** as other answer describes there is a second issue with the switch statments.  Try this manner to exit.

```
        while (ans == false) {  // start of while block
          System.out.println("Do you want to try again?");
          ans0 = KeyBoard.nextLine();
          ans0 = ans0.toLowerCase();
          switch(ans0){
            case "no":
              playing = false;
            case "yes":
              ans = true;
          }
        }    // end of while block
```

The above will loop until the answer either "yes" or "no", at which point it sets ans = true to exit the while (ans == false) loop.

if they answer "no" it will see playing = false to exit the above playing == true loop, otherwise it will loop the game again.

Comment: Gah!  Was in the middle of saying the same.

Comment: also the other answer on the switch block is correct as well and is a second issue; you need to set playing = false to exit the above while loop.

Comment: i changed my code with your sugestion but now it stops at the yes and it keeps asking at no

Comment: edit worked a lot. I have the last problem now. the second time the script runs and the scripts finishs it doesn't use the exit strategy. (it keeps looping the game you can't quit)

Comment: put an ans = false before the while loop, otherwise it is still sitting at ans = true from previous loop.

Answer (score 2):

Change your switch with:

```
switch(ans0){
        case "yes":
            ans = true;
            break;
        case "no":
            playing = false;
            break;
```

Answer (score 2):

The `break` in your switch only breaks you out of your switch. To exit the loop do this:

```
switch(ans0){
        case "yes":
            ans = true;
            break;
        case "no":
            playing = false;
            break;
```

This way your playing flag is set to false and you will exit the loop

Answer (score 0):

Couple of suggestion that I normally follow (Can't add it in comment so..) -

```
1. Name your final variables in all CAPITAL.
2. Change while(playing == true) to while(playing)
3. Change if (AI == rock && UserChoice == paper || AI == paper && UserChoice == scissor || AI == scissor && UserChoice == rock) to 
          if ((AI == rock && UserChoice == paper) || (AI == paper && UserChoice == scissor) || (AI == scissor && UserChoice == rock))
4. Change while (ans == false) to while (!ans)
5. Change "Do you want to try again?" to "Do you want to try again (yes/no)?"
```

Answer is already given :)

Answer (score 0):

You've done the work, so I feel OK posting this.  This is what I came up with.  I hope it's what you're looking for.  I refactored a lot of it so it was easier to read and run.  At least one issue is that there isn't any validation of input.

```
public class Game {

    private enum Choice{
        ROCK(1),
        PAPER(2),
        SCISSORS(3);

        int value;
        Choice(int i){
            value = i;
        }

        public static Choice lookup(int i){
            for(Choice c : values()){
                if(c.value == i){
                    return c;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    private enum Result{
        WIN,LOSE,DRAW
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner keyBoard = new Scanner(System.in);// naam scanner input
        Random rand = new Random();
        boolean playing = true;

        while(playing){
            int ai = rand.nextInt((3 - 1) +1) + 1;// maakt int AI een random getal nog niet af moet een range in komen
            Choice aiChoice = Choice.lookup(ai);
            Choice userChoice = getUserChoice(keyBoard);
            Result result = calculateResult(aiChoice,userChoice);

            System.out.println(getResultMessage(result));
            System.out.println(getComputerChoiceMessage(aiChoice));

            System.out.println("Do you want to play again?");
            playing = keyBoard.next().toLowerCase().equals("yes");
        }
    }

    private static String getComputerChoiceMessage(Choice aiChoice) {
        switch (aiChoice){
            case PAPER:
                return "The computer did paper";
            case ROCK:
                return "The computer did rock";
            case SCISSORS:
                return "The computer did scissors";
        }
        return "";
    }

    private static String getResultMessage(Result result) {
        switch (result){
            case WIN:
                return "You win!";
            case LOSE:
                return "You lost!";
            case DRAW:
                return "Draw!";
        }
        return "";
    }

    private static Result calculateResult(Choice aiChoice, Choice userChoice) {
        if(aiChoice == userChoice){
            return Result.DRAW;
        }
        if(aiChoice == Choice.ROCK && userChoice == Choice.PAPER ||
                aiChoice == Choice.PAPER && userChoice == Choice.SCISSORS ||
                aiChoice == Choice.SCISSORS && userChoice == Choice.ROCK){
            return Result.WIN;
        }
        return Result.LOSE;
    }

    private static Choice getUserChoice(Scanner keyBoard) {
        System.out.println("choose 1 for rock, 2 for paper and 3 for scissor");
        return Choice.lookup(keyBoard.nextInt());
    }
}
```

And some sample output

```
choose 1 for rock, 2 for paper and 3 for scissor
1
Draw!
The computer did rock
Do you want to play again?
yes
choose 1 for rock, 2 for paper and 3 for scissor
3
Draw!
The computer did scissors
Do you want to play again?
no

Process finished with exit code 0
```